# Spring Boot use separate user for flywaydb and JPA

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

```
flyway.password=pwd2 #does not take effect
flyway.user=user2 #does not take effect
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=pwd1
```

user1/pwd1 is used to run flyway db migrations as well as DML operations via JPA. Is there a way to get flyway db to use another credentials?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by specifying flyway.url too.

Comment: It worked for me but under spring.flyway.url! SB2 and Flyway 5

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing the Spring config file with the [Flyway config file](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/configfile). Try putting the Flyway config in a `flyway.conf` file instead of Spring's `application.yml` config file.

Alternatively, you can use [Flyway environment variables](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/envvars) like `SPRING_FLYWAY_USER` and `SPRING_FLYWAY_PASSWORD`. This is usually a good practice (secured) on cloud environments, as it can be filled from so-called secrets.